# Moment: not able to get the format

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have an api which returns the date which is human readable but not getting the data after parsing through moment;

The time which I am getting from api is

```
{"time": "Jun 27 2022 03:40:00:000PM"}
```

what I have tried is

```
let data = moment("Jun 27 2022 03:40:00:000PM").format()
also tried this:
let data = moment("Jun 27 2022 03:40:00:000PM").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

But not getting time. Every time I get the error

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Can someone guide  me how to tackle this types of dates.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks in advance for the interaction

Comment: Do you have control over the API?

Comment: no i do not have control over the api. I have to deal with this time format only.

Comment: That's a shame. One of the dupe targes should be of help.